# How to install the Code::Blocks IDE?

Tags: ide

I am using 64-bit Ubuntu and I want to install the Code::Blocks IDE. Is there any repository?

Comment: Cod::Blocks is in the Ubuntu repository.

Comment: @NlightNFotis Why ?

Comment: @NlightNFotis How do you aspect someone who is new to Ubuntu to manage all those stuff. So, this is the place where lone user get help from the communities. May be the question may sound stupid for the expert but for the newbies it's a serious thing. Plz. don't understand estimate us instead lit the flame of 'Humanity'. Anyway, I consider you all as the expert, Plz don't hesitate to help me in the future.

Comment: @Namshum My comment was not to flame you, rather, to imply that any **serious software developer is a problem solver**, and he should **find an answer to his problems by himself** and not ask others for solutions to **his** problems, unless he has done all he could to find an answer, and yet he failed.

Comment: @Namshum You may also find my answer here to be of use: http://askubuntu.com/questions/196717/to-write-a-batch-processing-script-which-runs-on-bash/196722#196722

Comment: @Namshum.. You are welcome to ask whatever you like we are here to help each other

Comment: @NlightNFotis Thanks! for your link. And also I want to tell you that I am trying to learn some programming in C++.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install software using the Ubuntu Software Center?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/66447/how-do-i-install-software-using-the-ubuntu-software-center)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Code::Blocks is a cross-platform Integrated Development Environment
> (IDE). It is based on a self-developed plugin framework allowing
> unlimited extensibility. Most of its functionality is already provided
> by plugins. Plugins included in the base package are:
>
> - Compiler frontend to many free compilers
> - Debugger frontend for GDB (and CDB for windows platforms)
> - Source formatter (based on AStyle)
> - Wizard to create new C++ classes
> - Code-completion / symbols-browser (work in progress)
> - Default MIME handler
> - Wizard to create new Code::Blocks plugins
> - To-do list
> - Extensible wizard based on scripts
> - Autosave (saves your work in the unfortunate case of a crash)<sup>1</sup>

To download and install click the image below.

[image: Install via the software center]

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:Ubuntu Apps Directory</sup>

Comment: The current version in the Ubuntu 12.04 repository is 10.05-2, while the [website](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries#linux64) has Code::Blocks 12.11 available for download.

Comment: @DrewNoakes you can manually download the deb packages and install those with DPKP ,

Answer (score 23):

It's available in the Software Center.

Just open the Ubuntu Software Center and search for its name.

Or install via the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

Comment: I got this error :- Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/w/wxwidgets2.8/libwxbase2.8-0_2.8.12.1-6ubuntu2_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.92.182 80]
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

Comment: Doesn't show up in software center for me.

Comment: That terminal command works, even though it doesn't show up in the software center.

Answer (score 18):

> **Note:** [damien-moore's PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edamien-moore/+archive/ubuntu/codeblocks-stable) mentioned in this answer has Code::Blocks version 16.01 and does not support releases after 16.04.

From the Code::Blocks website, the download page for Linux points to the [Code::Blocks Release Builds PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Edamien-moore/+archive/ubuntu/codeblocks-stable), which is probably the easiest way to install a reasonably up-to-date version of Code::Blocks. To install Code::Blocks from the aforementioned PPA, do the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:damien-moore/codeblocks-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install codeblocks codeblocks-contrib
```

Comment: This is much better method.

Answer (score 5):

You can install CodeBlocks using following command:

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

Answer (score 1):

If you plan to develop on ubuntu its beneficial to learn how to compile code from the command line ... even the codeblocks IDE

download source code

http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads

pick file similar to codeblocks_16.01.tar.gz

cd into where you wish to expand the tarball and issue

```
tar xvf /path/to/codeblocks_16.01.tar.gz

cd codeblocks-16.01.release

autoreconf -fi  #  
./configure  #  standard check to confirm your have necessary libs
make -j4   # actual compile and link step
sudo make install  # install binary and its libs
sudo ldconfig  # this registers your new libs
```

now its installed ... go ahead and launch

```
codeblocks   #  Voila you have launched your new IDE
```

If above gives errors you probably have yet to install upstream dependancies ... if so this may help

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential 
sudo apt-get install -y libwxbase3.0-0v5 libwxbase3.0-dev libwxgtk3.0-dev wx3.0-headers wx-common
sudo apt-get build-dep codeblocks
```

Comment: While your way is correct it should state that compiling Code::Blocks against wxwidgets 3 is not yet properly supported and may result in crashes within the IDE, but the wxwidgets 2.8 is not available anymore with 16.04 LTS.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is to run:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get install codeblocks
```

Your repository list isn't up to date, you got update suggestion from Ubuntu. If you want to be Linux programmer I'm recommending you getting LPIC-1 knowledge before you start. It is crucial to understand basics of this system to code for it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use newest version from 'Jens'
Even if it's unofficial, we can get all versions.
You can also choose repositury or just'deb' file.

http://apt.jenslody.de/

For stable release, add these two lines to the `sources.list` file and refresh the package index

```
deb [arch=amd64,i386] https://apt.jenslody.de/stable jessie main
deb-src https://apt.jenslody.de/stable jessie main
```

Then install the codeblocks. Tested on Ubuntu 12.04 - both 32 and 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing the packages manually. Connecting via *FTP* to the archives with your file manager. Or download manually from the site in the link below.

***Alternatively*** install it via GUI with *GDEBI* by clicking each deb file which will indicate if another package/dependency is missing then install that one first. You can start with *Codeblocks* and *GDEBI* will indicate the directly related packages and you follow that and avoid getting lost in dependencies.

Don't know if a file association can be made to click and trigger *GDEBI* directly from the browser.

[FTP : Archives](ftp://anonymous@archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/codeblocks)

The server is : ftp.archive.ubuntu.com

And the path to *Codeblocks* is : ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/codeblocks

In a terminal type : ftp

Then comes the propmt

```
ftp> open ftp.archive.ubuntu.com
user
anonymous
>Type password
"leave blank"
cd ubuntu/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/codeblocks
get *.deb
```

The files will be saved to *HOME*

delete the *DEBs* of the undesired architecture

Save this script :

```
#!/bin/bash
# Reference
# http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/bash-for-loop/
# https://www.dbsysnet.com/2015/12/using-bash-arrays-with-examples
BLOCKS=( hello young flying sun you don look old at all);
for LIST in 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
do
    echo ${BLOCKS[LIST]};
done;
```

You can check for answers on how to use the script, Make it executable and run it from the *HOME*.

Replace echo with the bash command to install packages :

```
dpkg -i ${BLOCKS[LIST]};
```

Change the list message with the list of packages for *Codeblocks* in the *HOME* folder

```
ls *.deb
```

Match the number of packages to the list of 12 elements

If 20 elements then **1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20**

Comment: Kinda complicated way of doing it, especially theres one problem with installing by `dpkg` you have to get the order right in which you install the packages and your script does not solve that.

Comment: Right, And what about then using apt-get instead? Downloading the packages from archives and putting those on /var/... and telling apt-get to install that specific version ? That would be a bang if it worked. I think apt-get check the archives first to avoid re-downloading packages.

Comment: This could work, but don't nail me down on it, would have to setup a VM to test it tho. I compiled my Code::Blocks from scratch.

Comment: Yes. as a true free user, a VM.  That's why I want to use snapshots to revert those kind of things, there is __apt-btrfs__ I kinda remember but it seemed to be unsupported I need it so I would fork it. Does Code Blocks has a MAKE RUN rule ? @Videonauth

Answer (score 0):

## I have quite a few methods do whatever you like

#### 1. Download binaries

Current Version is `20.03` if you are reading this in future, go to this URL and check for the latest version http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/binaries

Download the zip and install it on your system, there are `.deb` files.

#### 2. Add PPA

You can add the official PPA from the launchpad, and can get updates as soon they release

### Notice here - Ubuntu 20.04 is still not supported so don't get frustrated if its not installing in 20.04

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:codeblocks-devs/release\
&& sudo apt-get update \
&& sudo apt-get install codeblocks codeblocks-contrib
```

if you have 18.04 then do this ->

```
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu bionic main\
&& deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/codeblocks-devs/release/ubuntu bionic main
```

#### 3. Use apt

```
sudo apt install code-blocks
```

I'm not 100% sure but i think these packages are maintained by `canonical` itself, so updates will be very slow, but there are only one or two updates in code block every year so you wont miss a lot of things even if you use this one.

#### Good luck doing C++, Its not python.