# How to install latest Code::Blocks from tar.xz?

Tags: software-installation, code-blocks

How to install latest Code::Blocks using `codeblocks_17.12-1_amd64_stable.tar.xz`?

Software center has an old version and I am not able to configure. How to install? Why is there no documentation for installing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install the Code::Blocks IDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198442/how-to-install-the-codeblocks-ide)

Comment: @TalhaJunaid No answer from the linked page seems to get the version  17.12.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should extract downloaded archive with

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget https://kent.dl.sourceforge.net/project/codeblocks/Binaries/17.12/Linux/Debian%20stable/codeblocks_17.12-1_amd64_stable.tar.xz
tar -xf codeblocks_17.12-1_amd64_stable.tar.xz
```

Then install extracted deb-packages:

```
sudo dpkg -i *17.12*.deb
```

And finally install missed dependencies:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Please note that `codeblocks-contrib` will be removed on 16.04 LTS and on 18.04 LTS because of missed `libhunspell-1.4-0` dependency.

Do not forget to install compiler such as GCC.

Comment: Worked perfectly in Ubuntu 18.04. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you apply the same steps already explained

> sudo dpkg -i *17.12*.deb

and

> sudo apt-get install -f

But with debian testing .deb instead of debian stable, libhunspell version is in sync and all work ok, including the codeblocks-contrib package.