# Can I install the previous version of Codeblocks "Codeblocks 17.12" on Ubuntu 20.04 lts?

Tags: software-installation, code-blocks

Now Codeblocks 20.03 is available. But I want to install codeblocks's previous version 17.12. Is it possible to install the previous version on ubuntu 20.04? If yes then how? Please help me to do it and If I install the previous version will it do any misbehave?

Comment: What happens when you use this https://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/17.12/Linux/Debian%20stable/ ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install latest Code::Blocks from tar.xz?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030720/how-to-install-latest-codeblocks-from-tar-xz) Though the title says latest, the question was about 17.12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first you have to download the file that you want to install. As you says the version 17.12 is in tar.xz package.
So you have to extract it by using this command
`tar xvf /filename/` . After extracting install all .deb file using `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`.

Happy Coding.

Comment: Thank you so much sir.