# Can't Install Latest Code::Blocks on 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: 20.04, downloads, code-blocks

I tried to install Code::Blocks by following this answer, but I cannot install the application:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [question you link to](https://askubuntu.com/questions/198442/how-to-install-the-codeblocks-ide) points to [a PPA that hasn't been updated in four years](https://launchpad.net/%7Edamien-moore/+archive/ubuntu/codeblocks-stable). This would never work on your system. As it stands, there is no PPA to install Code::Blocks in Ubuntu 20.04 at this time. There is [one that supports up to 19.10](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecodeblocks-devs/+archive/ubuntu/release), but it has not been updated in almost a year.

If you would like to use this application, the simplest and safest way to do so would be to [download the binary](http://www.codeblocks.org/downloads/26#linux) from the Code::Blocks site (you'll probably want the `codeblocks_20.03_amd64_stable.tar.xz` file), expand it, then install the application manually.

Hope this helps.